# Python storing results from a while loop inside a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, while-loop

I have a for-loop where I calculate the solution of an equation with a given 30k step. Inside this for-loop, there is a while loop where I calculate a second equation with a given step size (starting from 1 to 2 with a step size of 0.0001 = total of 10k steps) and try to compare the results with a solution of for-loop.

There is one solution for each while loop (within 10k) that corresponds to the first equation that I need to store (inner_value). So, in total, I need to store 30k solution array.

However, I am only able to store 1 solution. When I try to append outside the while loop, it says the solution (inner_value) is not defined. I appreciate any help.

Comment: The source of your error is typically due to failing to define the variable for the reference scope.  From a quick scan of your code, however, this doesn't seem to be the case unless I am missing something. What exactly is the error message you are receiving?  Which variable is it referencing?

Comment: It complains when you try to append what with what, exactly? The code that doesn't work and the error message would help a lot here

Comment: please reduce your code to the absolute minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. Your code contains a lot of noise at the moment which has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I have tried to simplify the code before posting here but it was not a good idea. I added the full code. value_out1 gives only 1 output where it should give an array of solution for each for loop @itprorh66

Comment: @OctaveL . Sorry for that, that was my attempt to simplify my code to prevent any confusion. Now, the code should work

Comment: @Raphael, I did as much as I can. It is working now but as I mentioned it only produces 1 output for "value_out1" where it supposed to do for each for loop (30K in total)

Comment: add a print command inside the if previous is not None... maybe it enters to it only one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RHS1 = 4.8e1*alpha_1**(0.4)*M1**(-7./6.)*cell_12**(-0.35)*mm_30 * P**(-1.083)
previous = None
Rin1 = 1.0 # ADDED THIS LINE
while Rin1 < 2:
    print(Rin1)
    LHS1 = (Rin1**(3.125))*np.absolute(1-Rin1**(-1.5))
    Rin1 = Rin1+ss
```

You forgot to reset Rin1 to its default value, didn't you?

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand how stupid my mistake was.